# Coding style: ref / out variables, good/bad practice?

Tags: c#, coding-style

I've come across code in this format quite regularly.. (And I guess I'm nitpicking) I know, classB can be labeled as ref/out. I'm asking from a viewpoint of if going by good/best practices, or am I misunderstanding the point of ref/out.

The reason I'm asking is, that I'm finding it confusing at times not knowing if properties in my object is going to be updated or not :/ (Meaning id need to drill down into the method to see whats going on)

```
    public ClassB GetSomething()
    {
       var classB = new ClassB();

       ClassA classA = .... // some code to get new obj

       //from a glance i'm not ale to tell that classB gets updated/assigned to  
       this.DoSomething(classA , classB);

       return classB;
    }

    private void DoSomething(ClassA classA, ClassB classB)
    {
          classB.Property = classA.something.Property;
    }
```

Comment: Probably belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: You do understand there is a huge different between `ref` and `out` right?  Why do you think this method requires an `out` or `ref` parameter?

Comment: Yes i know there is a difference :), my question is prob more style related and fueled by frustration at this point, (... also, i was thinking it might belong on another stack exchange flavour, but i want sure...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, assuming that `ClassA` and `ClassB` are reference types, then `classA` and `classB` are references being passed by value. If you assign a new value to them inside the body of your method, then this will not have any effect outside the method scope. For example;

```
private void Caller()
{
    var classA = new ClassA();
    var classB = new ClassB();

    DoSomething(classA, classB);

    // classA and classB still point to the instances from before the call to DoSomething()
}

private void DoSomething(ClassA classA, ClassB classB)
{
      classA = null;
      classB = null;
}
```

However, you can mutate their properties, as you are doing in your example.

The `ref` and `out` keywords are used to indicate that the parameters are being passed by reference, and therefore the method *can* assign new values to the reference parameters. The difference is that `ref` parameters must be assigned to before being passed into the method, whereas `out` parameters must be assigned to before the method is exited.

Answer (score 2):

Is your `ClassA` actually a class?

In that case, no, you don't need `ref`/`out`, and furthermore, it will be misleading.

Class instances are passed by reference anyway. `ref` means that the reference *itself* may be changed (and `out` means that it *will* be changed) and the change will be visible outside the method, which is not the case for your code: in your example only the object referred to by this reference is changed.

In C#, there is no special modifier which governs whether the method can or cannot change the object's fields, call its mutating methods or otherwise change it. The methods can access everything which is publicly available. (Or protected, or private, if within the same class.) And the changes are seen outside, because, well, both pieces of code are looking at the *same* object.

Note that it would work differently for value types (structs): with structs, the called method gets not the *reference* to that value type, but rather a *copy* of it. So any changes to the struct\s fields (provided that you've got a mutable struct, which is bad per se) won't be visible outside without `ref`.

Comment: `"Class instances are passed by reference anyway."`  No, they are still passed *by value* by default, unless you add the out/ref modifier.  The variable **is** a reference itself, and that reference is what is being passed by value.  Method parameters only actually pass instances of objects when those objects are value types.

Comment: @Servy: Just curious: is there a difference between "class instance is passed by ref" and "ref is passed by value"? (I know that the variable is a reference.)

Comment: Yes, there is an *enormous* difference between a value passed by reference and a reference passed by value.  Most of the *important* differences are conceptual, but they still do leak into a number of practical differences.  Effectively it's the difference between a class passed by value and a struct passed by reference.  If you assign a new instance to a struct passed by ref it's reflected in the original, that's not the case for classes.  You can hold onto the reference of the class after the end of the method, but not for the struct.  Need more than 500 chars to keep going.

Comment: @Servy: sorry, still don't get it. Could you please make an example of method which gets a class reference as input, so that the program behaves differently in the different cases (class instance passed by ref vs. class instance ref. passed by value)?

Comment: @Rohan: the question was directed to Servy

Comment: @RohanBüchner You shouldn't be, because they're *wrong*.  Most of the answer here make statements that are simply incorrect and many of the, such as this one, indicate a lack of understanding of the fundamental concept of reference/value types and the semantics for passing function parameters

Comment: @Vlad Example code of the difference between passing a reference by reference and a reference by value?  (That's different than what I was referring to before.)  Sure, [see this not incorrect answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13456882/1159478).  Since the references are passed by value `classA` is not changed in the caller.  If you passed the references by reference, they would be.

Comment: @Servy: your example doesn't work: pass by reference doesn't mean that the changes in the reference of the caller will be changed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference.

Comment: @Vlad That's exactly what it means actually, by definition.  `public static void method(ref object obj) { obj = null; }`  Pass anything that's not null to that method, and then after calling that method it will be null.  Then remove `ref` and see it not be the case.

Comment: @Servy: again wrong. Your code passes reference by reference, not object by reference.

Comment: @Vlad You kept switch between what you were saying; I was quite clear that that was an example of passing a reference by reference.  You refereed to `"changes the reference of the caller"` if the caller is a value type then it doesn't have a reference.  In any case, if you want to refer to changing a value passed by reference, that is easy enough to demonstrate:  `public static void method(ref int n) { n = 5; }`  Pass a value that's not `5` and it will be changed to `5`.  What would you expect to happen here?

Comment: @Servy: I am quite clear in my answer: class instances (not references, instances!) are passed by reference. Could you please be so kind to find where I am saying about passing reference by reference in my answer (without `ref` modifier)?

Comment: @Vlad `"I am quite clear in my answer: class instances (not references, instances!) are passed by reference"`  Instances of classes aren't passed at all, ever, in managed C#.  The only time an instance of an object is passed is when it's a value type.  When you have a variable of a class it *is* a reference.  It is not itself the instance of the class, it is just a reference to it.  When you pass that variable you are passing the reference, and you are either passing that reference by reference, or you're passing that reference by value (there is a major difference between the two).

Comment: @Servy: Can you back your claim that "in C# instances are not passed by reference"? What is your understanding/definition of "passing instance by reference"?

Comment: @Vlad All variables are passed by value by default.  A parameter is only passed by reference if it is preceded by `ref` or `out`.  This can be seen in 1.6.6.1 in the C# language specs.

Answer (score 2):

That code is fine - classB is already a reference. If you used ref, then you would have a reference to a reference, which is not what is intended here. But it has it uses too; consider this:

```
private void Foo()
{
    object myObject = new object();
    DoSomething(ref myObject);
}
private void DoSomething(ref object myObject)
{
  myObject = new object();
}
```

When DoSomething is called, it changes the object that the myObject variable in Foo is assigned to, to be pointing at the object created in DoSomething.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking ref/out is not required as you are making a change to an object (reference type). I think the clarity with which methods are written is a separate issue, one which can be resolved by suitable design patterns etc.

Answer (score 1):

As Cal279 mentioned, you don't need the ref modifier because you're not actually changing the value of classA's pointer, but rather changing a property of a reference type.

C# doesn't have explicit syntax to mark that a given method makes change to a parameter's state, but you can do so yourself by naming the method appropriately: instead of `DoSomething`, make sure the method is called `UpdateClassB` or `FillClassBFromClassA`, or even `SynchronizeEntities`. Something that explicitly describes what it does.